# Static method needs to call autowired repository for method security in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In current Spring Boot, `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` and `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` are deprecated, so IntelliJ warns and manual recommends `@EnableMethodSecurity` instead.

The following tutorial based on `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` works fine at this point

- [How to create a custom security expression method in Spring Security](https://medium.com/@islamboulila/how-to-create-a-custom-security-expression-method-in-spring-security-e5b6353f062f)
- [A Custom Security Expression with Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression)

And, I tried to modify my code to use `@EnableMethodSecurity` after reading the official document:

- [Method Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html#jc-enable-global-method-security)

It illustrates the code below:

```java
@Bean
static MethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    handler.setTrustResolver(myCustomTrustResolver);
    return handler;
}
```

Tip says:

> We expose `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` using a `static` method
> to ensure that Spring publishes it
> before it initializes Spring Security’s method security `@Configuration` classes

However, I need to inject my repository dependency bean in my `CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot`. In `static` method, the autowired instance variable cannot be accessed.

I'd like to use `PreAuthorize` with my custom method such as "isUser", "isMember" using my own repository. Of course, I can solve my problem using `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`, but I want to write my code in a correct way.

Comment: Whats i `CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot` you have not posted that code?

Comment: @Toerktumlare
The first link "How to create a custom security expression method in Spring Security" has the `CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot` code. It resolves UserService using setter injection.  Finally, I decided not to use `EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` because it seems that it's so tricky to inject service.

Comment: Im sorry but im not going to click random links that contain huge tutorials and try to ”figure out” what you mean. Please include all code relevant in your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can inject a repository directly in your bean method, even if it is static:

```
@Bean
static MethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler(MyRepository repository) {
    // do something with repository
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler handler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    handler.setTrustResolver(myCustomTrustResolver);
    return handler;
}
```